# I am trying to do eager loading using Entity Framework where I have one-to-many relationship between region and client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

This is my `Region` model class:

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients {get; set;}
}
```

and my `client` model class:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Regions {get; set;}
    public string AlternateNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
   
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageSrc { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Fluent API for relation mapping:

```
 builder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Regions)
        .WithMany(x => x.Clients)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.Id);
```

Here I need the `RegionId` as a foreign key, but I am unable to get it; all I am getting is `ClientId` as foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You have to  add a RegionId column to the Client table

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
   
    .....
   public Guid RegionId {get; set;}
   public virtual Region Region {get; set;}
   ....
```

and dbcontext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Region)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Clients)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.RegionId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
                  
            });
```